# posts_per_page showing 16 elements instead of 3

Tags: wp-query, query

I need help with this. Whatever I add to 'posts_per_page' value, it shows 16 posts for some reason..

```
<?php

        $args = array(
          'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                  'key' => 'featured_posts',
                  'compare' => '==',
                  'value' => '0'
                )
              ),
          'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => '3',
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        $total_posts = $the_query->found_posts;

        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
          while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {  $the_query->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'insert/insert', 'boxes' );
          }
          wp_reset_postdata();
        }
       ?>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <?php if($total_posts <= 3) { ?>
        <div class="col-12" id="all-shown">
          All Posts Shown
        </div>
      <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="homepage-loadmore col-12" id="load-more">
          <a href="#" id="loading-more">Load More Posts</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12" id="all-shown" style="display: none;">
          All Posts Shown
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query might be picking up sticky posts. To ignore them, try this:

```
    $args = array(
      'meta_query' => array(
            array(
              'key' => 'featured_posts',
              'compare' => '==',
              'value' => '0'
            )
          ),
      'post_type' => 'post',
      // Changed '3' to 3, since WP_Query expects an int.
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
      // Ignore the sticky posts.
     'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    );
```

Comment: Yeah the problem was in sticky posts, now it works! You saved me a lot of time, thank you so much!